# UWP position flyout at mouse cursor

Tags: c#, uwp, flyout

I have a grid with a load of textblocks inside and a flyout with various options attached to the grid.

```xml
<FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
    <MenuFlyout>
        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="EditButton" Text="Edit" Click="EditButton_Click"/>
        <MenuFlyoutItem x:Name="DeleteButton" Text="Delete"/>
    </MenuFlyout>
</FlyoutBase.AttachedFlyout>
```

The problem is that the flyout will appear in the same fixed spot somewhere in the middle of the grid or I can set it programmatically to appear at an element. I want it to appear wherever the mouse was right clicked. Is this possible or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: Can you show us the code that is opening the flyout?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know how are you showing the `Flyout`, but in my app, I use the `RightTapped` event of my `ListView` and following code in the `RightTapped` event handler to achieve the same thing as you want.

```
private void MyListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var tappedItem     = (UIElement)e.OriginalSource;
    var attachedFlyout = (MenuFlyout)FlyoutBase.GetAttachedFlyout(MyListView);

    attachedFlyout.ShowAt(tappedItem, e.GetPosition(tappedItem));
}
```

Comment: MenuFlyout can show in special position but you cant show the Flyout in a particular position.

Comment: Showing at a specified position breaks the Tapped event of child MenuFlyoutItems. Probably a bug in the latest UWP SDK.

Comment: UPDATE: This can be worked around by calling ShowAt(tappedItem) first, then calling ShowAt(tappedItem, e.GetPosition(tappedItem)).